# How to avoid the warning: return type requires unchecked conversion?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have the following example:

```
class uncheckedreturn
{
  static abstract class Abstract
  {
    abstract public <A extends Abstract> A make ();
  }

  static class Concrete extends Abstract
  {
    public Concrete make ()
    {
      return new Concrete();
    }
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {}
}
```

The `Abstract` class is requiring the definition of a `make` method and the `Concrete` class is extending the `Abstract` class and defining the `make` method. When I compile it, I get the following warning:

```
$ javac -Xlint:unchecked uncheckedreturn.java && java uncheckedreturn
uncheckedreturn.java:10: warning: [unchecked] make() in Concrete overrides <A>make() in Abstract
    public Concrete make ()
                    ^
  return type requires unchecked conversion from Concrete to A
  where A is a type-variable:
    A extends Abstract declared in method <A>make()
1 warning
```

I do not understand which conversion takes place here and why it is unchecked. The abstract method `make` is specified for a type extending `Abstract`. And `Concrete` is exactly doing this: extending `Abstract`. So why is `Concrete` differing from `A`?

How to change the code to get rid of the warning?

**Update**

I think I am a step further in understanding what the problem in the code is. The generic abstract method `make` allows the following implementation with is obviously not what I want to allow:

```
class uncheckedreturn
{
  static abstract class Abstract
  {
    abstract public <A extends Abstract> A make ();
  }

  static class Concrete extends Abstract
  {
    @Override
    public OtherConcrete make ()
    {
      return new OtherConcrete();
    }
  }

  static class OtherConcrete extends Abstract
  {
    @Override
    public Concrete make ()
    {
      return new Concrete();
    }
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {}
}
```

Maybe there is no way to keep just the method generic.

Comment: `<Concrete>make()`? A correct declaration doesn't need generics btw: `public abstract Abstract make()` works just as well as a declaration.

Comment: @AlexR make should return the extending class not the extended.

Comment: @AlexR `<Concrete>make()` produces just a syntax error. It should be easy to find out yourself with my example.

Comment: Put something into your `main` method. That is: Show us how you would like to **create** and **use** instances of `Concrete` and `OtherConcrete`, and particularly, how you would like to **call** the `make` method.

Comment: @Marco13 I asked for an explanation of the warning. The warning does not depend on the way I intend to use the classes. Maybe I will ask a question in the future how to solve my problem in another way, but that will be another question. Right now I would like to understand just the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the requirement hardly makes any sense (apart from looking like an attempt to emulate a `clone()` method).

Initially, you said that the return type of the `make` method should be "any" subtype of `Abstract`. This usually simply means to use covariant return types, like in this example:

```
class uncheckedreturn
{
    static abstract class Abstract
    {
        abstract public Abstract make();
    }

    static class ConcreteA extends Abstract
    {
        @Override
        public ConcreteA make()
        {
            return new ConcreteA();
        }

    }

    static class ConcreteB extends Abstract
    {
        @Override
        public ConcreteB make()
        {
            return new ConcreteB();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConcreteA a0 = new ConcreteA();
        ConcreteA ma0 = a0.make();

        ConcreteB b0 = new ConcreteB();
        ConcreteB mb0 = b0.make();

    }

    // This is possible, but you'd like to not allow this
    static class ConcreteC extends Abstract
    {
        @Override
        public ConcreteA make()
        {
            return new ConcreteA();
        }
    }

}
```

As mentioned in the comment (and emphasized in your EDIT) this does not prevent a class from returning subtype of `Abstract` that is not its "own" type, and you made clear that you essentially are looking for a "`this`-type" that could allow you to write something like

```
class Concrete {
    public <SameAsThis> make() {
        return new Concrete();
    }
}
```

but something like this does not exist in Java. It could, to some extent, be achieved with the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern): You can specify a type parameter for the class that determines the return type of the method, and make sure that this type matches the class:

```
class uncheckedreturn
{
    static abstract class Abstract<A extends Abstract<?>>
    {
        abstract public A make();
    }

    static class ConcreteA extends Abstract<ConcreteA>
    {
        @Override
        public ConcreteA make()
        {
            return new ConcreteA();
        }

    }

    static class ConcreteB extends Abstract<ConcreteB>
    {
        @Override
        public ConcreteB make()
        {
            return new ConcreteB();
        }
    }

//    // Now, this is no longer possible:
//    static class ConcreteB extends Abstract<ConcreteB>
//    {
//        @Override
//        public ConcreteA make()
//        {
//            return new ConcreteA();
//        }
//    }

    // But this still IS possible, but may also not be desired...
    static class ConcreteC extends Abstract<ConcreteA>
    {
        @Override
        public ConcreteA make()
        {
            return new ConcreteA();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConcreteA a0 = new ConcreteA();
        ConcreteA ma0 = a0.make();

        ConcreteB b0 = new ConcreteB();
        ConcreteB mb0 = b0.make();
    }
}
```

But again, there is a case where the type of the *class* type parameter may be "wrong", which would allow it to implement the method with a "wrong" return type.

Additionally, you said that you'd like to *"keep just the method generic"*, but there simply is no type information at this point. There are basically two things that can determine the compile-time type of a returned value:

- The type of the object that the method is called on (including covariance)
- The type parameters of a generic method

But neither of them can fulfill the requirements that you stated:

- The return type, even if it is covariant, can be *any* subtype of the return type
- The type parameters of the generic method can be equipped with lower bounds (like `Abstract`, in your case) but not with upper bounds or a concrete type

---

From a more high-level point of view, there may be alternatives for this method. It could be more appropriate to use a `Factory` here, once as `Factory<ConcreteA>` and once as `Factory<ConcreteB>` (or simply a [Java 8 Supplier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)). But this depends on the overall goal and the intended usage of these classes.

Comment: Yes it is similar to `clone` with the difference, that only a part of the object gets cloned.

Comment: The classes are already factories. I need to create a factory based on an existing factory to change a feature of the factory but the type compatibility with the original factory must be keept.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the `make` method to be able to return an object of a type that varies in subclasses, so you should make a generic type parameter for that type, and the concrete implementation can apply the appropriate type argument for the type it makes:

```
static abstract class Abstract<A> {
  abstract public A make();
}

static class Concrete extends Abstract<Concrete> {
  public Concrete make() {
    return new Concrete();
  }
}
```

Comment: In your example `A` can be anything. I need `A` to be something extending `Abstract`.

Comment: "I need A to be something extending Abstract." It doesn't make sense to have such a requirement, from a type safety point of view. The code as written is type-safe. Also, "extending Abstract" meaning *any* Abstract? That would hardly seem useful.

Comment: `A` should be an extending class, which makes perfectly sense for me, because it is exactly what I need.